# Is there a way to use CQL functions inside JSON literals in INSERT?

Tags: json, cassandra, cql

Is there a way to use CQL functions inside JSON literals in INSERT? For example:

```
CREATE TABLE oranges (
    id uuid,
    color text,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

These work:

```
INSERT INTO oranges JSON '{
    "id": "f8f54a3c-b91c-4ff5-8f31-5784beafe1dc",
    "color": "red"
}';

INSERT INTO oranges (id, color) VALUES (
    uuid(),
    'red'
);
```

But this doesn't:

```
INSERT INTO oranges JSON '{
    "id": "uuid()",
    "color": "red"
}';
```

I realize CQL has no way to guess when the JSON string is a CQL function call, but I was curious if there was support for this somehow.

Comment: If this were allowed (it isn't), it would be very hard to guard against maliciousness - it would be an injection attack vector. It would also not allow sending data that "looked like some CQL operation but wasn't".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, once that a JSON format is detected, Cassandra will assume that it is a JSON document and nothing more.

Looking on the bright side, this is something good, combining different languages on the same method would make the application harder to maintain.

Comment: Nit: There is no 'detecting JSON'. Rather the insert form (with [JSON ..])` as defined by the grammar and parsed by the engine is used - this is a distinct calling variation, not a detection/run-time selection.